# What is the closure of $ C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})$ in Sobolev $ W^{1,p} $ norm?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

For $1 \leq p < \infty, n\geq 1 $ my guess of the answer was $ W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but I can't prove the inclusion $ \overline{C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})} \subseteq W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) $.

Any hints or partial solutions( like for $ p = 2$) would be extremely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @user103402 right, I should edit .....sorry !

Comment: OK, but the question remains: how can the closure in $W^{1,p}$ norm contain something that's not in $W^{1,p}$?

Comment: As you said, $ 1/|x|^n \notin W^{1,p} $, hence its evidently not in the closure in that norm....but i am asking for whether you can characterize the closure of test functions in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\} $.

Comment: If by $C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ you mean the set of infinitely many differentiable functions with compact support contained in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ then its closure with such norm is $W_0^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case $n = 1$ or ($n \ge 2$ and $p> n$), you have the embedding from $W^{1,p}$ to $L^\infty$. In this case $\overline{C_c^\infty}\subsetneq W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$.
Indeed, every limit point of $\overline{C_c^\infty}$ is continuous and zero at $0$.

In the other case, you get $\overline{C_c^\infty} = W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$. This can be seen by taking an arbitrary function in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$, mollifying it and truncating it (smoothly) at $0$ and $\infty$.

All steps but the truncation at $0$ are standard. For this truncation, recall, that there is a function $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$, which is equal to one in a neighbourhood of $0$ and has an arbitrary small $W^{1,p}$-seminorm. Multiplication with $1-\varphi$ will do the job.

Comment: Okay, but where exactly the second argument breaks down in the first cases ?

Comment: And can you elaborate little more how to choose such a $ \varphi $ ?

Comment: In the case $p > n$, you cannot truncate at zero as above. For choosing $\varphi$: Take something as $\psi(x) = |\log(|x|)|^s \, |x|^r$, with suitable powers $r,s$. This should give you a function in $W^{1,p}(B_{1/2}(0)) \setminus L^\infty$. Now, you scale this function down (such that the norm becomes small), truncate it to values between $0$ and $1$ and mollify it with a small mollifier.

Comment: Got it... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the closure is with respect to the $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\})$ norm so what you are asking is whether $W^{1,p}_0(\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}) \subseteq W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$.

Not exactly, since the two spaces consist of functions defined on different domains. But if $\Omega$ is any open set and you extend a function $f \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ to be zero outside $\Omega$, the extension belongs to $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$.